# Python create list from a other list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, user-defined-functions

i want do edit a list in a python def function and get as return a new function. In the function the list should be sorted and some of the list-items should be replaced. The return should be a new list! Thx for help in advance..

i have a `list1 = [a, d, b]` the `d` should be replaced with a `c` and the list should be sorted. the new list should be `[a, b, c]`.

Comment: Please tell us what you have done to solve it and what problem you have encountered?

Comment: `sorted(['c' if i == 'd' else i for i in ['a', 'd', 'b']])`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Assuming that your letters start at the first letter and are in alphabetical order, this should work:

```
letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']

def Correct(l):
    l.sort()
    i = letters.index(l[0])
    return letters[i:min(len(letters), i+len(l))]
```

And to try it out:

```
test = ['a', 'd', 'b']
Correct(test)
```

Which gives:

```
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

EDIT:

Some users pointed out that this is just for this specific case. So, this solution should work:

```
def Swap(l, c):
    l.pop(1)
    l.append(c)
    return l
```

Comment: I don't think your solution does what the question asks. If the passed list is, for example, test = ["b", "c", "e"], your function returns ['b', 'c', 'd']; if you have `test = ["y", "d", "z"]`, `Correct(test)` returns `['d', 'e', 'f']`. In the specific case, it works by chance

Comment: @nikeros, the OP states that the 'list should be sorted', clarifying your query by stating that it should not be judged by the first character, rather the alphabetically lowest.

Comment: @:arryTheLlama the example input provided `list1 = [a, d, b]` is not sorted: in my understanding what the user simply wants is 1) substituting ds with cs 2) have a sorted output. As stated before, your solution does not achieve that or better, it does in that specific case, but the logic is flawed To me it is scary that the user has judged it as the one doing the job, honestly.

Comment: @nikeros you're right. this is definitely NOT an answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove 'd', append 'c' and sort:

```
def edit_list(list1, old_letter, new_letter):
  list1.remove(old_letter)
  list1.append(new_letter)
  sorted(list1)
  return list1
```

output:

```
>>>list1 = ['a', 'b', 'd']
>>>edit_list(list1, 'd', 'c')
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Comment: Thank you! But i have to solve it in a def function with parameters: list1, old_letter, new_letter) and the return should be a new list2..

Comment: @RMJ7 I've updated my solution. Is it what you are looking for?

Comment: yeah you solved my problem.. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

In a more general setup, if you have a dictionary of remappings like

```
m = {"d":"c",} # you can add as many mappings as you want
```

You can achieve your result as follows:

```
new_list = sorted([m.get(k, k) for k in list1])
```